# Get unique user information for calls using Mobile Application Security

Tags: node.js, mobile, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

Given an Node.js app making use of Mobile Application Security - I want to get a unique identifier from the request based on the client making the call. So for example, my hybrid mobile app authenticates with Google, sets the security token, makes the call to my Node.js app. All of this works fine, but I'd like to associate a unique ID with the client so that when I do operations like data fetching, I can use the token as an identifier. Is that possible out of the box or do I need to include it in my calls?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is a limitation of MAS and the hybrid SDK. You will need to implement that functionality yourself.

Apologies for the inconvenience.